# Касания в веб-приложении для сенсорных мобильных устройств

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Есть ли готовые библиотеки под это дело? Если нет, как делать вручную? Сейчас использую стандартную GWT 2.1.0.

Comment: а какая задача? касание = клик.

Answer (score 1):

```
обьект.onclick = имя_вашей_функциии;
```

На touchScreen'ах касание это событие `click`